# Meaning of indispensable

Tags: meaning-in-context

Murthy says, "Computers have played indispensable part in our lives. "
What does the word **indispensable** mean in this sentence?

Comment: As a side note, not related to your question: Shouldn't the question be: "Computers have played indispensable part in our lives." ?

Answer (score 1):

**Absolutely necessary things**.

> Computers are **very necessary** in our lives.

Link to [the Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/indispensable)